# vb.net Error when trying to install a windows service

Tags: windows, vb.net, service, installation

Im trying to create a windows service with vb.net but when I run:

```
InstallUtil.exe myservice.exe
```

I'm getting the following error in the MyService.InstallLog file:

```
Restoring event log to previous state for source DebtorInvoiceMailingService.
An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the System.Diagnostics.EventLogInstaller installer.
System.Security.SecurityException: The source was not found, but some or all event logs could not be searched.  Inaccessible logs: Security.
An exception occurred during the Rollback phase of the installation. This exception will be ignored and the rollback will continue. However, the machine might not fully
```

**DebtorInvoiceMailingService.vb**

```
Imports System.ServiceProcess
Imports System.Timers

Public Class DebtorInvoiceMailingService
    Inherits ServiceBase
    Private _timer As Timer
    Private _lastRun As DateTime = DateTime.Now
    Private _notificationsManager As Notifications

    Public Sub New()
        Me.ServiceName = "DebtorInvoiceMailingService"
    End Sub

    'When service starts
    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        MyBase.OnStart(args)
        'This object will do what im looking for (monitore a folder)
        Me._notificationsManager = New Notifications
        Me._timer = New Timer
        'Service will be executed every 24 hours
        Me._timer.Interval = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24
        Me._timer.Enabled = True
        'Service will execute timer_Elapsed()
        AddHandler Me._timer.Elapsed, AddressOf timer_Elapsed
    End Sub

    'When service stops
    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        MyBase.OnStop()
        Me._timer.Dispose()
    End Sub

    'Function executed every 24 hours
    Private Sub timer_Elapsed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ElapsedEventArgs)
        If (Me._lastRun.Date > DateTime.Now.Date) Then
            Me._timer.Stop()
            'You have to stop your timer because if the task that you 
            'are about to perform takes longer than the timer.interval
            'the task will be executed multiple times
            Me._notificationsManager.execute() 'this function will send an email
            Me._lastRun = DateTime.Now
            Me._timer.Start()
        End If
    End Sub

    Shared Sub Main()
        ServiceBase.Run(New DebtorInvoiceMailingService)
    End Sub
End Class
```

**ProjectInstaller.vb**

```
Imports System
Imports System.ServiceProcess
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Configuration.Install

<RunInstallerAttribute(True)> _
Public Class ProjectInstaller
    Inherits System.Configuration.Install.Installer
    Public WithEvents ServiceProcessInstaller1 As ServiceProcessInstaller
    Public WithEvents ServiceInstaller1 As ServiceInstaller

    Public Sub New()
        MyBase.New()
        Me.ServiceProcessInstaller1 = New ServiceProcessInstaller()
        Me.ServiceInstaller1 = New ServiceInstaller()
        'ServiceProcessInstaller1
        Me.ServiceProcessInstaller1.Account = System.ServiceProcess.ServiceAccount.LocalSystem
        Me.ServiceProcessInstaller1.Password = Nothing
        Me.ServiceProcessInstaller1.Username = Nothing
        'ServiceInstaller1
        Me.ServiceInstaller1.Description = "Auto mailing invoices to debtors every 24 hours."
        Me.ServiceInstaller1.DisplayName = "DebtorInvoiceMailingService"
        Me.ServiceInstaller1.ServiceName = "DebtorInvoiceMailingService"
        Me.ServiceInstaller1.StartType = ServiceStartMode.Manual
        'ProjectInstaller
        Me.Installers.Add(Me.ServiceProcessInstaller1)
        Me.Installers.Add(Me.ServiceInstaller1)
    End Sub
```

Please Can someone help me? Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be sure to run the InstallUtil from a command windows launched "As Administrator".